# Issue in MongoAtlast database connectivity error

Tags: database, mongodb, backend

```
first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0-p6qwr.mongodb.net cluster0-p6qwr.
mongodb.net:27017]
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to connect to the database using mongoAtlas. I did with a dummy small app, over there, it gets connected, but in the main app there seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use VSCode, but when using that, I find it best to have two terminals open in the first I usually connect via shell follow its instructions and use the command `mongod` in the other I run `npm start`.

Make sure your project is in a process.env. But generally, it may help to know how you are trying to deploy your project if it's using yarn or node.

Also, it may help to know are you connecting via shell, application, or cluster.

Comment: am adding a cluster than connecting via an application, in which the string is generated.

Comment: @Striver79. Since it's hard for me to know where in the installation connection process you are and the objective of the project, the best I can give you is a demo guide. Of a plan that works, and you can reverse engineer or see where you went wrong. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FOq4cUdH8k&t=3138s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FOq4cUdH8k&t=3138s). His video is quite detailed in setting up and integration walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

`gettaddrinfo ENOTFOUND` means that the address you're trying to connect to cannot be found. Are you sure that you're using the correct URL to connect to the database and that the URL isn't malformed?

Comment: Yes am very much sure, since I created a dummy app and used the exact same url and it works perfectly over there